# Cutting acrylic bath panel to fit profile of baseboard trim

Tags: bathroom, cutting

We are decorating our bathroom and the current bath panel is looking a bit yellow.

We have found a lovely clean white bath panel made from Acrylic, but we have a skirting board on both walls where the bath panel touches.

What i am wanting to know is the best way to cut the acrylic so that it fits nicely with the skirting without any gaps.

The skirting is similar to the image below.
[image]

Comment: The material of the sample that you have appears to be MDF - Medium Density Fiberboard. MDF is not designed to be used in wet or damp areas. The glue that binds it together does not hold up to water, and will swell up and become waterlogged.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the "panels" will cover the existing (fiberglass?) tub walls? The skirting (molding?) from your photo looks to be made of MDF (medium density fiberboard). MDF won't last very long in a wet environment.

To install the acrylic sheets, if possible, remove the skirting and then measure the wall height and subtract 1/2-3/4 inch. The panels will easily install and the skirting will cover the gap.